# How to specify the id of a select element generated with Rails 5 association helper

Tags: html, select, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to specify a different id for the element, but I am getting the auto generated id for the html select element:

My code:

```
<%= f.association(
  :manager,
  label: 'Manager',
  id: 'not_doing_anything',
  collection: [@company.manager].compact
) %>
```

How can I specify a different id?

Answer (score 0):

does it work when you try using html{} like below?

```
         <%= f.association(
          :manager,
          label: 'Manager',
          :html => { id: "some_new_id" },
          collection: [@company.manager].compact
        ) %>
```

Comment: No luck with that, not even :select_html. I am having a hard time finding clear documentation about this...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
<%= f.association(
  :manager,
  label: 'Manager',
  id: 'not_doing_anything',
  collection: [@company.manager].compact,
  input_html: { :id => 'my_own_id'}
) %>
```